# How can I handle exit argument?

Tags: c, shell, exit-code

I am building a simple shell I want to handle the argument of exit. How can I handle it here?

I have already handle exit but I want to handle exit with argument.
Usage: exit status, where status is an integer used to exit the shell

**For example**

```
exit 98
exit 1
```

**Present output**

```
sh: No file or directory found
```

**Expected Output**

Exit the shell with the specific status code

**shell.h**

```c
  #ifndef  SHELL_H
  #define SHELL_H
  
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <string.h>
  
  void print_prompt(void);
  void tok_str(char *, char **);
  int add_path(char **cmd);
  void print_env(char **); 
  #endif
```

**shell.c**

```
#include "shell.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
        char *buf = NULL;
        size_t buflen = 0;
        char *cmd[20];

        do
        {
                fprintf(stderr, ":) ");

                if (getline(&buf, &buflen, stdin) == -1)
                {
                        if (feof(stdin))
                        {
                                free(buf);
                                buf = NULL;
                                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                        }

                        perror("Error occurred");
                        free(buf);
                        buf = NULL;
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                if (buf[0] == '\0' || strcmp(buf, "\n") == 0)
                {
                        free(buf);
                        buf = NULL;
                        continue;
                }

                if (strcmp(buf, "exit\n") == 0)
                {
                        free(buf);
                        buf = NULL;
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                }

                if (strcmp(buf, "env\n") == 0)
                {
                        print_env(env);
                        free(buf);
                        buf = NULL;
                        continue;
                }

                tok_str(buf, cmd);
                add_path(cmd);

                if (fork() == 0)
                {
                        execve(cmd[0], cmd, env);
                        printf("%s: No such file or directory\n", argv[0]);
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                }else
                {
                        wait(NULL);
                        free(buf);
                        buf = NULL;
                }

        } while (1);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**utils.c**

```
#include "shell.h"

void tok_str(char *buf, char **cmd)
{
        char *ptr;
        int i = 0;

        ptr = strtok(buf, " \n");

        while (ptr)
        {
                cmd[i] = ptr;
                ptr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                i++;
        }

        cmd[i] = NULL;

}


int add_path(char **cmd)
{
        const char *PATH[] = {"/usr/local/bin/ls", "/bin/", "/sbin/", "/usr/bin/", NULL};
        unsigned int i = 0;
        struct stat st;

        while (PATH[i])
        {
                char s[120] = "";
                strcat(s, PATH[i]);
                strcat(s, cmd[0]);
         
                if (stat(s, &st) == 0)
                {
                        cmd[0] = s;
                        return (0);
                }

                i++;
        }



        return (-1);
}

void print_env(char **env)
{
        int i = 0;

        while (env[i])
                printf("%s\n", env[i++]);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `strcmp(buf, "exit\n"`, check if `buf` starts with `exit`.  Then parse the integer value of the argument and pass that to `exit` instead of `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Comment: Start by learning how to write parsers, because `strcmp` will not get you very far if you want anything more than the absolute basics.